# c:choose with multiple c:when - fall-through switch

Tags: jsf, loops, jstl, break

If i have this code on my jsf page:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${empty example2}">
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>     
</c:choose>
```

it will work like java `switch` statement with `case` and `break` - if first when is true, second won't be test, right ?

What should i write to get "`switch` statement with `case` but without `break`" :

when first `C:when` is true something add to page and when second is true something is add to page too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're thus basically looking for a fall-through switch. That isn't possible with `<c:choose>` as it represents a true `if-else...`. JSTL does not offer any tags for a fall-through switch.

Your best bet is to use multiple `<c:if>`s wherein you also check the preceding condition as an `or` condition.

```
<c:if test="#{empty example1}">
    ...
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{empty example1 or empty example2}">
    ...
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{empty example1 or empty example2 or empty example3}">
    ...
</c:if>
...
```

As you're using JSF, an alternative is using component's `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty example1}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty example1 or empty example2}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty example1 or empty example2 or empty example3}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
...
```

The difference is that it's evaluated during view render time instead of during view build time. So if you were for example using this inside a `<h:dataTable>` based on the currently iterated row, the `<c:if>` wouldn't have worked the way you'd expect. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

To eliminate the condition checking boilerplate, you could use `<c:set>` to create new EL variables. This works in both approaches.

```
<c:set var="show1" value="#{empty example1}" />
<c:set var="show2" value="#{show1 or empty example2}" />
<c:set var="show3" value="#{show2 or empty example3}" />

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{show1}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{show2}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{show3}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it isn't possible with `c:when`. You can use `c:if` instead:

```
<c:if test="${empty example1}">
      "example1 empty"
</c:if>

<c:if test="${empty example2}">
     "example2 empty"
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty example1 and not empty example2}">
     "both not empty"
</c:if>
```